# Older artifacts never showing in Temple Run 2

Tags: temple-run-2

I have played Temple Run 2 for 6 weeks (over 500 games) and I am only getting artifacts of "Frozen". The earlier ones (Rings, Masks, Critters, Floral and Relics) never show. I did get the seasonal relics but they do not repeat after completing them.

To get to level 11 I now need to complete 3 different categories of artifacts. Without them showing I can't progress. Any idea what to do about this?

Playing on Android...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The game was adjusted a few versions ago to skew towards artifacts in sets that are not yet complete.  So that can affect the distribution that you see.

If you haven't gotten all 11 Frozen artifacts, then you may be more likely to get those now, and once you get all 11, probably the distribution may return to being more even or even tilting towards sets that you haven't yet completed.

Another note is that if you want to specifically avoid Frozen artifacts, you could try running on the other map (the original one, "Sky Summit.")  I'm not sure if it is still the case, but when the Frozen map came out, the Frozen artifacts were only appearing on the new map and not the old one.

Comment: Thank you, I will try the other map. I do have all 11 Frozen artifacts, probable already 10x over... Still no others showing. Lets see if the other map will work

Comment: Yes, that works, for the first time after 100s of Frozen artifacts I got a floral one in the other map.

Comment: I should have tried this much earlier... Anyhow it is a bug, hopefully sorted out in a later update. Thank's Purple!

Comment: After the latest update artifacts are now grouped by map so it's clear where to find what :-)